# ag-grid overlayLoadingTemplate add hyperlink and click enable

Tags: typescript, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag-grid ,while loading the data I want to show the message using overlayLoadingTemplate and also hyperlink for cancel the loading if it take more time to load the data . we added hyperlink but it was not clickable . How to clickable the hyperlink 
 this.gridOptions.overlayLoadingTemplate = 'loading......  Cancel...';
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the ag-grid overlay uses the `pointer-events: none;` style. You can easily fix this by setting pointer-events to auto in your template code. Something like:

`this.options.overlayNoRowsTemplate = '<div style="pointer-events: auto;">This is my template copy. Visit <a href="http://www.example.com/docs">our documentation</a> to learn more.</div>'`